# Extract values from JSON text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
   "head":{
      "vars":[
         "uri",
         "label"
      ]
   },
   "results":{
      "bindings":[
         {
            "uri":{
               "type":"uri",
               "value":"http://tematres.befdata.biow.uni-leipzig.de/vocab/?tema=751"
            },
            "label":{
               "type":"literal",
               "xml:lang":"en",
               "value":"15n"
            }
         },
         {
            "uri":{
               "type":"uri",
               "value":"http://tematres.befdata.biow.uni-leipzig.de/vocab/?tema=916"
            },
            "label":{
               "type":"literal",
               "xml:lang":"en",
               "value":"16s analysis"
            }
         },
         {
            "uri":{
               "type":"uri",
               "value":"http://tematres.befdata.biow.uni-leipzig.de/vocab/?tema=622"
            },
            "label":{
               "type":"literal",
               "xml:lang":"en",
               "value":"16s rrna"
            }
         },
         {
            "uri":{
               "type":"uri",
               "value":"http://tematres.befdata.biow.uni-leipzig.de/vocab/?tema=917"
            },
            "label":{
               "type":"literal",
               "xml:lang":"en",
               "value":"16s rrna gene analysis"
            }
         },
         {
            "uri":{
               "type":"uri",
               "value":"http://tematres.befdata.biow.uni-leipzig.de/vocab/?tema=618"
            },
            "label":{
               "type":"literal",
               "xml:lang":"en",
               "value":"18s rdna"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Is there any way to get only the `uri` value and the corresponding `label` value in a map or so, to fill a table with these values later.

Comment: Your question title is asking how to parse some JSON. Your question body gives an example of JSON, but then asks about how to extract specific data from the resulting JavaScript object. What problem are you actually having?

Comment: @Quentin, I modified the title. Thanks for the remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply iterate over like

```
json = "your json";

yourMap = [];
for(var i = 0; i < json.results.bindings.length; i++){ 

    yourMap[i]= [json.results.bindings[i].uri.value, json.results.bindings[i].label.value ];


}
console.log(yourMap);
```

here you have a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xyek6wda/4/

check the console output, it outputs an array containing the uri and label pairs

Comment: why downvoting the solution ?

Comment: @john the fiddle didnt work for me, neither on Chrome nor on IE8, upvoted though

Comment: @auicsc you must check the console output ;-)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Andy now it does, just added .value -.-

Comment: Thanks! but how can I map the two? For example, I would like to fill a select with `id=uri.value` and the text to be `label.value`

Comment: made an update, simply pushed into an array, also updated fiddle

Comment: youre very welcome, most important is you get the idea and can reproduce such case at any time again on your own

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the information you need into an array. Here I've added the label and URIs to objects that you can loop over when you need to:

```
var results = json.results.bindings.map(function (el) {
    return { uri: el.uri.value, label: el.label.value };
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s45v9noh/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is actually a better solution than the one provided above!